# Writing a rails gem with many sub classes / modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Help trying to write an internal gem / plugin for US based county information.  I would like to keep things organized by county since each county would require unique parsing of information.

Directory structure would be something like:

- lib
- - county_info
- - - state (all the states would be here stored in something like f_l.rb)
- - - - f_l.rb
- - - - a_l.rb
- - - - counties (will hold all the counties for the state in files like (dade.rb, broward.rb)
- - - - - dade.rb
- - - - - broward.rb

I would like to then be able to drill down via `CountyInfo::State::FL::Dade.hello`

Originally thought below would work:

```
require 'county_info/state'
class CountyInfo
end

Dir[[File.dirname(__FILE__), '/*/*.rb'].join].each{ |f| require f } # loads all folders with the names of each state
class  State < CountyInfo
end

Dir[[File.dirname(__FILE__), '/counties/*.rb'].join] .each{ |f| require f } # loads all the counties for this each state
class FL < State
end

class Dade < FL
  def hello
    return "hello I am florida"
  end
end
```

But keep getting error when launching app:

```
    ../app_name/lib/county_info/fl/counties/dade.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant FL (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because `FL` inherits from `State` it doesn't mean that it is part of that class or inside that namespace.

You should just be able to call `Dade.new.hello`

If you want to have them in that namespace hierarchy you want to nest them

```
class CountyInfo

  class State

    class FL

      class Dade
        def hello
          "hello I am florida"
        end 
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Only problem is that county names overlaps in states so it would need something like FL::Dade.hello.

Comment: Never mind, what you listed does let me do FL::Dade.hello.  Thanks!